# Pytesseract on AWS Lambda: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, tesseract

Lambda AWS: python 3.8

ARN tested:

- arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pytesseract:15
- arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pytesseract:16
- arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pytesseract:17

Lambda AWS: python 3.7

ARN tested:

- arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:113088814899:layer:Klayers-python37-pytesseract:13

`lambda_function.py`:

```
import json
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        body = {
            "text": pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('random_text.png')),
        }
    except Exception as e:
        body = str(e)

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }


    return response
```

No error when I import everything, the error come when I try to do an action with `pytesseract.image_to_string()`

Because import in python 3.7/3.8 with corresponding ARN work, I suppose that the error is really particular and concern `pytesseract`.
But why isn't it handle by the ARN ?
I saw other post talking about tutorials but I'm always stuck on this precise error: `tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH`

Comment: How did it go? Did you setup `tesseract` with your lambda?

Comment: Nope, i failed. :/

Answer (score 2):

> But why isn't it handle by the ARN ?

The layer is only for [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) wrapper around the actual `tesseract` binary. It does not come with the `tesseract` program.

So you have to build `tesseract` binary yourself for a lambda environment, and bundle it with your lambda function. One way of how to do it is shown [here](https://typless.com/tesseract-on-aws-lambda-ocr-as-a-service/).